# Problem with Imagemagick import (import-im6.q16) jammy/gnome

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-22.04

I use Imagemagick's "import" (import-im6.q16) a lot for capturing screen data.  And it works great on my primary workstation using the Mate desktop.

But I am trying to use it on Jammy/Gnome and it just hangs.

Nothing in any of the obvious logs (syslog,Xorg). Searched the web and the Imagemagick communities and come up empty.

Executing `import tmp.png` should turn the "cross-hair" cursor on and allow selection of a region of the default X display.  Upon "mouse up", the selected region is written to the file specified.  An existing file will be overwritten permissions permitting. The suffix should be an image file type or errors can occur (.pdf is an example).

Can anyone confirm this is broken or working with Gnome?

Comment: I am not an expert on import or on Gnome, but have you tried just the import on known good png without all the rest of your code.

Comment: oh, yes.  it still hangs without creating the file.